# Print environment using R

Tags: r, function, class, development-environment, environment

I'd like to write a function whose the output be an object of the class `myclass` with vector, list, integer an so on. Similarly to `lm`function. I tried to use an `environment`, but when I printed the function value the result is

```
#Term 1
> fit1
<environment: 0x00000000220d1998>
attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
```

However, when I print the `lm` function, the result is

```
> fit2
Call:
lm(formula = variable1 ~ variable2)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)         variable2  
         49.0802            0.3603
```

I know to access the individual values of the `environment` using `$`. But I'd like that the object was printed equal to `lm` function as showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
variable1 <- rnorm(10)
variable2 <- rnorm(10)
fit1 <- lm(variable1~variable2)
fit2 <- fit1
class(fit2) <- "myclass"

# have a look at stats:::print.lm
# and copy that function, hence define it as print method for your class or edit further:
print.myclass <- function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) {
  cat("\nCall:\n", paste(deparse(x$call), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), 
      "\n\n", sep = "")
  if (length(coef(x))) {
    cat("Coefficients:\n")
    print.default(format(coef(x), digits = digits), print.gap = 2L, 
                  quote = FALSE)
  }
  else cat("No coefficients\n")
  cat("\n")
  invisible(x)
}

# now print
print(fit2)

# or
fit2
```